# Intuition behind logloss function

Tags: log-loss

I have a difficulty understanding the intuition behind the logloss function since it seems to totally ignore negative examples where y = 0.

The images below visualize my question to some extend:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Your advice will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, however read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression for the cross entropy for logistic regression. Your loss is not specified correctly if this is what you intended to do.

Answer (score 8):

The formula you used, seems to be

$$
H(X) = -P(X)\log P(X),
$$

the definition of [*entropy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). You seem to be asking about *cross-entropy loss*, also known as [*log-loss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression), which is defined as

$$
L(y, \hat y) = \underbrace{-y \log(\hat y)}_{\text{when } y=1} \;\underbrace{- (1-y) \log(1-\hat y)}_{\text{when } y=0}
$$

where $y \in \{0, 1\}$ is the label and $\hat y$ is the predicted probability for the label. So the loss is zero for perfect classifications $y = \hat y = 1$, or $y = \hat y = 0$, and logarithmically increases otherwise.